# How do I pass UserData to a Beanstalk instance with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I need the application server, which is beanstalk instances, to do some actions upon startup and I thought of running a bash script passed to the instance with the UserData property which is available to regular EC2 instances.

I've found several example CloudFormation templates which does this with regular EC2 instances, but no example with Beanstalk. I've tried to add this to the properties field for the application:

```js
    "MyApp" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application",
      "Properties" : {
        "Description" : "MyApp description",
        "ApplicationVersions" : [{
          ...
        }],
        "UserData" : {
          "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
            "#!/bin/bash\n",
            "touch /tmp/userdata_sucess\n"
          ]]
        }},
        ...
```

I also tried to add to the environment part:

```js
    "MyAppEnv" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment",
      "Properties" : {
        "ApplicationName" : { "Ref" : "MyApp" },
        "Description" :  "MyApp environment description",
        "UserData" : {
          "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
            "#!/bin/bash\n",
            "touch /tmp/userdata_sucess\n"
          ]]
        }},
        "TemplateName" : "MyAppConfiguration",
        "VersionLabel" : "First Cloud version"
      }
    },
```

In both cases this resulted in failure when trying to create the stack. Does anyone know if it is possible to pass UserData to a Beanstalk instance using CloudFormation. If so - can you provide an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to have all the advantages that Beanstalk offers - like not having to patch the OS which Amazon does for you - this isn't possible. One option is to create a custom AMI where you include the needed scripts, but then you must manage the OS yourself with security patches. Read more [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=81687&tstart=0).

Comment: @tronda, do you know whether it is still the same 6 years later?

Comment: Sorry, have not worked with Beanstalk since this post. @AlexanderF.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `.ebextensions`, see [Amazon docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html).

An example:

```
packages:
  yum:
    bison:              []
    libpcap-devel:      []
    libpcap:            "1.4.0"
    golang:             "1.13.4"
    git:                []

commands:
  20_show_info_pkgs:
    env:
      GOPATH:           /usr/local/gocode
      PATH:             $PATH:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/usr/local/bin
    ignoreErrors:       true
    command:            |
      ls -l /usr/local /usr/local/g*
      env
      yum list bison libpcap-devel libpcap golang git
      which git
      which go
      git --version
      go version
      goreplay version
      true
```

Comment: This example doesn't have anything to do with setting the user data. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ronrothman a year and a half later... you can't set user data for the instance, but you can use .ebextensions to run commands when the instance starts, achieving the same effect (since instances are controlled by Elastic Beanstalk). Seems a bit convoluted TBH, but it does work (at least for the cases I've tried)