# elastic-beanstalk docker app not updating upon deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a `Dockerfile`/`elastic-beanstalk` app in a `git` repo that pulls a tarball of the current release of the application from `s3` and launches it.  This works great the first time I deploy; the Docker container gets built, and the app launches and runs correctly.  The problem comes after I make a change to the app, re-upload the tarball to `s3` and run `eb deploy`.

```
$ eb deploy
INFO: Environment update is starting.
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).
INFO: Successfully built aws_beanstalk/staging-app
INFO: Successfully pulled yadayada/blahblah:latest
INFO: Docker container 06608fa37b2c is running aws_beanstalk/current-app.
INFO: New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances.
INFO: Environment update completed successfully.
```

But the app has not updated on `*.elasticbeanstalk.com`.  I'm guessing since the `Dockerfile` hasn't changed, docker doesn't rebuild the container (and pull the latest application tarball).  I would like to be able to force a rebuild but the `eb` tool doesn't seem to have that option.  I can force a rebuild from the website console, but obviously that is no good for automation.  I am committing each change to `git` and I was hoping that `eb` would use that to know that a rebuild is necessary but that doesn't seem to make any difference.  Am I using docker/elastic-beanstalk in the wrong way?  Ideally I want to commit to `git` and have beanstalk automagically re-install the app.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with using Docker for CI is that it doesn't act like a script in that it won't rebuild unless the `Dockerfile` changes.  So you have to put the stuff that needs to be rebuilt every time in a startup wrapper script rather than in the `Dockerfile`.  So I moved the part that  downloads the application tarball into a script that the `Dockerfile` installs to the container.  Then when the container starts the tarball is downloaded and unpacked and only then can the real application start.  This works, and re-deploys now work as expected.  Its a bit aggravating to debug the process and leads me to the opinion that using Docker with EB for CI is a bit of a hack.

Comment: I have the exactly same problem. Re-deploy my web app but it's not updated. Can you provide more precision of how you fix that ? For the moment my Dockerfile call the .sh script which run my web server

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR:** You may be using ContainerDirectory without a HostDirectory or you may need to update the 03build.sh to build with the --no-cache=true flag.

After a bazillion hours later, I finally fixed this with my use case. I am using CodePipeline to run CodeCommit, CodeBuild, and Elastic Beanstalk to create a continuous integration / continuous delivery solution in AWS with docker. The issue I ran into was the CodeBuild was successfully building and publishing new docker images to AWS ECR (EC2 container registry) and EBS was correctly pulling down the new image, but yet the docker image was never getting updated on the server.

After inspecting the entire process of how EBS builds the docker image (there's a really great article [here, part 1](https://dev.bleacherreport.com/eb-under-the-hood-e7988736919f) and [here part 2](https://dev.bleacherreport.com/elastic-beanstalk-under-the-hood-2-nginx-89599e2179fb) that gives an overview), I discovered the issue.

To add to the article, there is a 3-stage process in EBS on the EC2 instances that are spun-up for deploying docker images.

1. pre
2. enact
3. post

This 3-stage process is a sequence of bash files that are executed which are located in `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/`.

The pre-stage contain the following shell scripts:

1. 00clean_dir.sh - Cleans directory where source will be downloaded, removes docker containers and images (e.g. cleanup)
2. 01unzip.sh - Downloads source from S3 and unzips it
3. 02loopback-check.sh - Verifies you don't have docker loopback setting set
4. 03build.sh - This is where the magic happens where EC2 will build your docker image from your Dockerfile or Dockerrun.aws.json. After much testing, I realized this build script was building my updated image but I modified this script to include the --no-cache flag on docker build as well.

The enact stage is where my caching issue was actually occurring. The enact stage consists of:

1. 00run.sh  - this is where docker run is executed against the image that was generated in the pre stage based on environment variables and settings in your Dockerrun.aws.json. This is what was causing the caching issue for me.
2. 01flip.sh - Converts from aws-staging to current-app and a lot of other stuff

When I would execute docker run from the image that was generated in Pre stage, 03build.sh, I would see my updated changes. However, when I would execute the 00run.sh shell script, the old changes would appear. After investigating the docker run command, it was executing

```
`Docker command: docker run -d  -v null:/usr/share/nginx/html/ -v /var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app:/var/log/nginx  ca491178d076`
```

The `-v null:/usr/share/nginx/html/` is what was breaking it and causing it not to update. This was because my Dockerrun.aws.json file had

```
"Volumes": [
    {
      "ContainerDirectory": "/usr/share/nginx/html/"
    }
  ],
```

without a referenced host location. As a result, any future changes I made, didn't get updated.

For my solution, I just removed the `"Volumes"` array as all of my files are contained in the docker image I upload to ECR. **Note:** You may need to add the --no-cache to the 03build.sh as well.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you might try using the user-data input when you define your instances in Beanstalk? Something like this could fire off right at the end of boot:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 cd /app/dir/home
 sudo docker pull username/container
 ... other things you may need to do ...
```

More that you can reference about user-data scripts and executables:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Comment: It looks like beanstalk doesn't support user data -- at least according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412231/how-do-i-pass-userdata-to-a-beanstalk-instance-with-cloudformation) and [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=81687).

Answer (score 0):

You should probably *[read this first](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-reference-get-started.html)* to get a better understanding of what we’re about to have our local site in our local GIT Repository and *[how to push it](https://www.otreva.com/blog/deploying-wordpress-amazon-web-services-aws-ec2-rds-via-elasticbeanstalk/)* up to ElasticBeanstalk to make the site live.

Find or Create a folder in the root of our site called *.elasticbeanstalk*.
Inside that folder we’ll make two files:

**config**

```
[global]
ApplicationName=YourApplicationNameFromAWSConsole
AwsCredentialFile=.elasticbeanstalk/aws_credentials
DevToolsEndpoint=git.elasticbeanstalk.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
EnvironmentName=EnvironmentNameFromAWSConsole
Region=us-east-1
```

**aws_credentials**

```
[global]
AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
AWSSecretKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Instead of `eb deploy` use [*`git aws.push`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31361109/4058484) to add and commit everything to ElasticBeanstalk

```
git add *.*
git commit -m "Adding AWS Configs"
git aws.push
```